# Unable to get HashMap value in Thymeleaf with long key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a page displaying visible lists to a user in a Thymeleaf/Spring Boot project. Lists have an `owner_id`, but not the owner's name, so to populate lists with their name instead of the id, I make a separate database call to retrieve all owners' ids and names, like so:

```
@Controller
public class ThymeleafController {

    private final ListController listController = new ListController();
    private final UserController userController = new UserController();
    private final ItemController itemController = new ItemController();

    @RequestMapping("/user/{user_id}")
    public String user_page(@PathVariable("user_id") long user_id, Model model) {
        // model.addtoAttribute("name", "World");
        UserMetaData user = userController.getUserMetaData(user_id);
        ArrayList<User> users = (ArrayList)userController.allUsers();
        HashMap<Long, String> userMap = new HashMap<Long, String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            userMap.put(users.get(i).getId(), users.get(i).getUserName());
        }

        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("userMap", userMap);
        return "user";
    }
}
```

And to populate the table with the owner name instead of the owner id, the following code is used in the template:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  ...
  <tbody>
    <tr th:each="publicList: ${user.public_lists}">
      ...
      <td th:text="${userMap[__${publicList.owner}__]}">Default Owner</td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, I get the following exception when loading the template.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1035E: The value '5760744339537920' cannot be parsed as an int
```

I'm not sure why this is trying to parse it as an `int` when the key is a `long`. Is there any way to get Thymeleaf to parse the value as a `long`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are two ways to get this to work:

```
<td th:text="${userMap.get(publicList.owner)}">Default Owner</td>
```

or

```
<td th:text=${userMap[__${publicList.owner + 'L'}__]}">Default Owner</td>
```

I would use the first.  The second you'd have to use in case of a form, I think.